# what is the difference between mean error and mean absolute error?

Tags: statistics

So, if I am not wrong, the formulae for mean error (ME) and mean absolute error (MAE) are following :

ME= 1/n (xi - yi)

MAE= 1/n Σ |xi - yi|

So, what are the major differences between two, other than that ME can be positive or negative but MAE is always positive. Thanks.

Comment: Edit this post! What your are saying here is meaningless.

Comment: Surely it should be $\sum_i|x_i-y_i|$ not $|\sum _i (x_i-y_i)|$.